# Валидация данных в микросервисной архитектуре

Tags: .net, архитектура, валидация, микросервисы

Я занимаюсь в данный момент проектированием микросервисной архитектуры. На данный момент у меня есть какое-то количество сервисов, которым нужны данные из другого сервиса

Допустим, сервис А, Б, С, Д. Всем им необходима информация из сервиса GEO, который содержит в себе информацию о странах, городах, таймзонах и яызках. Например, при создании данных в сервисе А мне необходимо проверить, что выбранная страна существует в системе (в сервисе GEO).

Придумал два решения:

1. С помощью grpc / http / orleans делать запрос на GEO сервис и валидировать полученные айдишники стран
2. При старте какого-либо сервиса получить данные из другого сервиса в локальную копию кэша (через те же http / grpc запросы), а в случае изменения этих данных реагировать на изменения с помощью azure service bus

В первом случае получаем сильную связанность сервисов, и рискуем получить каскадный отказ сразу кучи сервисов.

Во втором случае получаем намного менее сильную связанность за счёт того, что в случае выхода GEO сервиса из строя, у нас останется локальная копия в кэше.

От сюда возникает несколько вопросов

1. Какой в данном случае выбрать подход
2. Насколько хорошее второе решение с точки зрения архитектуры ?
3. Есть вообще другие решения этой проблемы (может через саги), к-ые я не додумал ?

С orleans до этого не работал, поэтому вообще не уверен, правильно ли я решил его применять. Был бы благодарен, если бы мне объяснили, в каких кейсах его можно применять

Comment: забыл добавить, что вариант с репликацией не подойдёт, тк. используются разные базы (azure sql server + azure cosmos db)

Comment: есть много разныъ подходов, как работать с кешем, и у каждого свои плючсы и минусы

Comment: например, для стран или городов, я бы наверное сделал кеш ещё в геосервисе, чтобы отрезать проблему с недоступностью геоданных

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На данный момент есть три базовых шаблона:

1. Прямые вызовы другого микросервиса.
2. Асинхронные вызовы с помощью брокера сообщений.
3. Дублирование данных.

На мой взгляд, в вашем случае лучше всего подходит третий вариант. Допустим у вас есть объект Страна, который содержит свойства Название, Валюта, ЧислоЖителей. Когда новая страна заводится в вашу систему, то должно генерироваться событие вида ICountryCreated, содержащее искомый объект, и отправляться в брокер.
Допустим, сервису А нужны для работы название и валюта страны, тогда вы подписываете его на получение события создания новой страны и при потреблении делаете сохранение в своей локальной базе только нужных для него двух свойств. Таким образом, разные микросервисы будут обладать разными знаниями о стране и будет определённая избыточность данных, но, одновременно, единственным источником правды будет оставаться ваш гео-сервис. Это позволит вашим сервисам сохранить несвязаность и синхронно обрабатывать запросы, которые как-то завязаны на геоданные.

Comment: да, решил сделать так же ) 
спасибо